# Change member group with Solspace User

Tags: members, solspace, solspace-user

I have a problem in Solspace User: Users can’t change their member group. In my case they should be able to deactivate their account.

I read about a similar problem on Solspaces' forum before:

http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewthread/3057/
http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewthread/13759/

But somehow I can’t solve mine in EE 2.8.

Users of member group 6 should be able to change it to member group 8 (deactivated)

- I unlocked member group 8
- In group 6 I set “Can change the group that a member is assigned to (Unlocked groups only” to “yes”.

This is my code:

```
{exp:user:edit allowed_groups="6|7" return="/profiel/"}
```

```
        <input type="hidden" name="member_id" value="{member_id}">
        <input type="hidden" value="7" name="group_id"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Ja, deactiveer mijn account" class="button" />
```

```
{/exp:user:edit}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.
Jef

Comment: Please detail what isn't working with your code sample.

Comment: Have you tried adding `group_id=""`? http://www.solspace.com/docs/user/edit/#group_id `group_id=""` is for giving admin powers to specific groups, `allowed_groups=""` is for limiting the groups a user can assign him/herself to.